# Asp Net Core Identity UserManager change context

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have implemented the microsoft identity framework, I'm using the UserManager via dependecy injection, since it is a multi-tenancy project I would need to extend the UserManager class to pass the desired context, I searched on google but I could not find or better adapt anything For my case.

```
  _userManagerRepository = new UserManagerRepository(new PortaleContext(tenantContext.Tenant))
  _userMgr = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

But when I run this method:

```
var passwordResetToken = await _userMgr.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user)
```

I get the following error:

```
<div class="titleerror">NotSupportedException: No IUserTokenProvider named &#x27;Default&#x27; is registered.</div>
    <p class="location">Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager&#x2B;&lt;VerifyUserTokenAsync&gt;d__122.MoveNext()</p>
```

And this is a part of my startup class:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
           // config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/App/Login";
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AdminContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
         {
             config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
             config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
             config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
             config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
             // config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/App/Login";
             config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
             config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
         })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PortaleContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In a nutshell, depending on which address the request arrives, the usermanager must update to its context

Answer (score 0):

This article references an error when calling AddDefaultTokenProviders() Twice. This may be your issue, I am looking for a similar solution but this one didn't work for me, but maybe you haven't seen it yet and it works for you.

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/972